# Tmux 1.9a - variable #{pane_current_command} doesn't work as expected

Tags: vim, cygwin, tmux

I'm trying to get [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) to work on my my Cygwin (Win7 x64) + Tmux 1.9a but it doesn't.  The reason is the variable `#{pane_current_command}` always returns `bash` instead of `vim`, so the script can't know if i have vim running in current pane or not. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Why don't you post an issue to the project's issue tracker?

Comment: i thought i find the answer here sooner